# Unbounded multidimensional index using Redis

Tags: caching, indexing, redis

I am using Redis in a project where I want to cache "timeitems", ie objects with a start- ("t_start") and endtime ("t_end").

I want to query the cache using a time window that also has a start- ("w_start") and endtime ("w_end). I want to find all timeitems that in overlaps the time window in any way.

I have already successfully implemented this using a sorted set with scores, (using score = t_start + (t_end - t_start) but that only gives me hits where the center of the timeitem is within the time window.

The overlap query in code is simply:

```
bool overlap = t_start < w_end && w_start < t_end
```

Now, I have read the documentation about multidimensional indexes here: http://redis.io/topics/indexes#multi-dimensional-indexes

But after banging my head for the better part of today I am starting to think that it wont work in this scenario because the problem is unbounded (?). That is, it it should detect an overlap from a time item that starts before and ends after the time window.

If anyone has worked on a similiar linearization problem, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Redimension is designed for indexing/querying n-dimensional data points. To use it in your case, t_start would be the first dimension and t_end the second dimension. Your query's ranges for each dimension should be:

1. t_start between 0 and w_end
2. t_end between w_start and +inf

Note 1: Instead of 0 and +inf you can actually keep track of min(t_start) and max(t_end)

Note 2: +inf should be sometime in 2038

Alternatively, instead of redimensioning it, you can use two Sorted Sets for timeitems - one for keeping t_start and one for t_end. The intersect from two `ZRANGEBYSCORE` operations (one on each set) would yield the timeitems overlapping the window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, those are indeed the ranges but I get the feeling that more or less ALL timeitems in the sorted set would be retrieved (to be filtered outside of Redis). Especially using the the second method (two sorted sets). The question is if the "redimensioning" and intersection is possible to do inside redis server using the technique described on redis.io?

Comment: Yes - use Lua scripts. For redimension, you can use my port: https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/3s0h73/luaredimension_redis_multidimensional_query/

Comment: Ok, I will certainly try to find time to try your Lua. From a mathematical viewpoint (and after starting to implement it using StackExchange.Redis) I have my doubts, since the examples concern finding if a multidimensional point lies within a certain range (of same dimension), while this scenario concerns finding if a range insersects with another range. Let me get back to you..

Comment: @RobertKling great - looking forward. Do note that the redimension Lua port runs in the server itself, rather than by an external client.

Comment: I'm a little stuck.. using StackExchange.Redis and I dont understand how to pass the parameters correctly. `Redis.ScriptEvaluate(loadedLua, ....);`